# Scala placeholder behavior

Tags: scala, foreach

Suppose `l = List(1, 2, 3):`

```
scala> l foreach { println _ }
1
2
3
scala> l foreach { println }
1
2
3
```

`l foreach { println _ } <=> l foreach { println }` because `_` can be omitted. But why does the following also produces the same result?

```
scala> l foreach { println(_) }
1
2
3
```

Shouldn't the `_` be bounded to println instead of foreach?
in other words:

```
l foreach { println(_) } <=> l foreach { println(x => x) }
```

and therefore throws an error on missing parameter type?
`l foreach { println(_.toString) }` produces the expected missing parameter type error

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` takes a function `A => Unit`, in this case, `Int => Unit`

`println` satisfies this condition, but it is a method, not a function.  Scala can get around this though, through a technique called eta expansion.  It creates a function that takes the inputs for the method and called the method with those inputs.  In your case, it looks similar to `(x: Int) => println(x)`.

Each way you've written accomplishes this.

`l foreach { println }`

Here Scala is able to infer that you want to treat `println` as a function and pass it to `foreach`

`l foreach { println _ }`

By adding the underscore you explicitly saying that you want to turn the method into a function

l foreach { println(_) }

This is similar to the last, for any method you call, you can use an underscore instead of passing a parameter.  By doing this, instead of calling the method you create a partially-applied function.  You then pass this function to `foreach`

l foreach { println(_.toString) }

This is quite a bit different.  `_.toString` creates a function `A => String` but Scala cannot figure out the correct type for A.  Another problem is not you are passing a value to `println`, so you are calling `println` and passing the result to `foreach` instead of turning it into a function.  `println` returns `Unit` which is the wrong type to pass to `foreach`

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the _ be bounded to println instead of foreach? in other words:
>
> ```
> l foreach { println(_) } <=> l foreach { println(x => x) }
> ```

No, this is specifically excluded by rules for placeholders in anonymous functions:

> [An expression e of syntactic category Expr binds an underscore section u, if the following two conditions hold: (1) e properly contains u, and (2) there is no other expression of syntactic category Expr which is properly contained in e and which itself properly contains u.](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#placeholder-syntax-for-anonymous-functions.)

"*Properly* contains" means `_` never binds itself, and so it never expands to `x => x`. In your last example, `_.toString` does properly contain `_` and so satisfies both conditions above.

Comment: Could you please explain why this
`def func1 : String => String = doubler(_.replace("a", "b"))` won't work, while this will work:
`def func2 : String => String = doubler(_.replace("a", "b"))`
The doubler functinon is something as `def doubler : String => String = _ * 2`.

What you said seems to make sense, but I still cannot apply that to this trivial situation.

Comment: @LucasLima I don't see any difference between `func1` and `func2`?

Comment: That is because I'm stupid and didn't post the right `func2`. Sorry.
`def func2 : String => String = _.replace("a", "b")`

Comment: `doubler(_.replace("a", "b"))` means `doubler(x => x.replace("a", "b"))` and `x => ...` is not a `String` and you can't apply `doubler` to it.

Comment: But the compiler is not even indicating that - it is trying to do the expansion, and then complaining about the lack of type for the underscore. What I fail to understand is why does it try to expand inside of the doubler call, instead of interpreting the underscore as being a string parameter from the outside function definition

Comment: Because that's the way it is defined to work (and can't change due to backward compatibility). Yes, I think it's something of a wart and one of the few things Kotlin (for example) does better.

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting that `println(x)` can also be written as `println x` in Scala. If there's only a single argument, the parenthesis are optional.